# My VHDL code compile but the RTL Simulation doesn't run

Tags: vhdl, clock, modelsim, test-bench

I am somewhat new to VHDL and am trying to create a simple code for a Flip Flop D. My code compiles correctly, however when I run my Testbench `tb_FlipFlopD` in ModelSim Altera, the program opens but there's no wave, and I don't have the option to add it either.
The bug is problaby in my Testbench.

My Top-level identity code `FlipFlopD`:

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;


    entity FlipFlopD is
        port( clock: in std_logic;
                D: in std_logic;
              Q: out std_logic
            );
    end FlipFlopD;

    architecture RTL of FlipFlopD is
    begin       
                Q <= D when clock = '1' and clock'event;    
    end RTL;
```

My Testbench `tb_FlipFlopD`:

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    entity tb_FlipFlopD is
    end tb_FlipFlopD;

    architecture teste of tb_FlipFlopD is

    component FlipFlopD is
    port (
            clock   : in    std_logic;
            D   : in std_logic;
            Q   : out   std_logic
    ); 
    end component;

    signal I: std_logic; 
    signal O: std_logic;
    signal C: std_logic := '0';
    constant clk_period : time := 1 ns;


    begin

    instancia_FlipFlopD: FlipFlopD port map( D => I, Q => O, clock => C);
    I <= '0', '1' after 1 ns, '1' after 2 ns, '0' after 3 ns, '1' after 4 ns;

    clk_process : process
    begin 
        C <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        C <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
    end process;

    end teste;
```

Comment: Did you run a simulation ? If yes, you will see several signals in the object pannel. Right click on those you want and click on "Add to waves".

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you simulation runs, but never stops; it just keeps on running forever.

Any VHDL (or Verilog) simulation will keep running if there is still stuff to do. This process:

```
clk_process : process
begin 
    C <= '0';
    wait for clk_period/2;
    C <= '1';
    wait for clk_period/2;
end process;
```

generates an *event* (a change) on the the signal `C` every `clk_period/2`. Forever. To cure this, you need to put something in to stop this, eg:

```
clk_process : process
begin 
    while not STOP loop
      C <= '0';
      wait for clk_period/2;
      C <= '1';
      wait for clk_period/2;
    end loop;
    wait;
end process;
```

The `wait;` at the end of the process, waits forever. Signal `STOP` is a `boolean`:

```
signal STOP : boolean := false;
```

Then you need something like this to drive signal `STOP`:

```
STOP <= false, true after 10 ns;
```

Comment: The "wait for" keyword suspends the simulation.

Comment: It suspends the process. It does not suspend the simulation.

Comment: Yes true, but I mean, the "wait;" do exactly the same : it suspends the process* indefinitely. It is like having wait for an infinite amount of time; so the simulator believes no more signals will evolve then stops the simulation.

However when you run a simulation on ModelSim, you just run the simulation step by step. I think you solve another problem : https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?198782-How-to-stop-the-simulation-in-VHDL-TB or here https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/VHDL-test-bench-to-stop-simulation-at-a-certain-time/td-p/843191

Comment: With Modelsim, I never added a way to stop simulation and it always worked out of the box. I just Simulate, then add the objects I need to the waves, click on run for some ns and that's it.